# A 10-digit number whose $n$th digit gives the number of $(n-1)$s in it

Tags: elementary-number-theory, decimal-expansion

There is a ten-digit number $X$ such that its first (left-most) digit is equal to the number of $0$s in $X$, the second digit gives the number of $1$s in $X$, and so on. The last (right-most) digit gives the number of $9$s in $X$.  Find $X$.

Aren't there a lot of possibilities for a  solution?

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you can solve it recursively.

1. The first number can't be 0, because then the number of zeros isn't 0
2. Can it be 9? => 9,000, 000,00? **NO**
3. Can it be 8? => 8,?00,000,010 **NO**- but there is contradiction
4. Can it be 7? => 7,?00,000,100 **NO**
5. Can it be 6? => 6,210,001,000 **Yes**
6. Can it be 5? => 5,???,???,???

And you play this way a little bit. I guess the solution is the only one

Answer (score 4):

**No.  There is exactly one.**

**+1 to Amulya for an interesting question.**

**+1 to ipoteka for doing it the hard way :)**

```c
/*
      There is a ten digit number X such that 
          its first (left-most) digit is equal to the number of 0s in X, 
          the second digit gives the number of 1s in X, 
          and so on. 
          The last (right-most) digit gives the number of 9s in X. Find X. 
          isn't there a lot of probabilities to the solution?
*/

#include <iostream>

int main
(
    void
)
{
    std::cout << "Working" << std::endl;
    const int N = 10;
    int digits[N] = { 0 };

    for (int a = 0; a < N; a++)    {   digits[a]++;    std::cout << "progress " << a << std::endl;
    for (int b = 0; b < N; b++)    {   digits[b]++;
    for (int c = 0; c < N; c++)    {   digits[c]++;
    for (int d = 0; d < N; d++)    {   digits[d]++;
    for (int e = 0; e < N; e++)    {   digits[e]++;
    for (int f = 0; f < N; f++)    {   digits[f]++;
    for (int g = 0; g < N; g++)    {   digits[g]++;
    for (int h = 0; h < N; h++)    {   digits[h]++;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)    {   digits[i]++;
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)    {   digits[j]++;



    if
    (
        (a == digits[0]) &&
        (b == digits[1]) &&
        (c == digits[2]) &&
        (d == digits[3]) &&
        (e == digits[4]) &&
        (f == digits[5]) &&
        (g == digits[6]) &&
        (h == digits[7]) &&
        (i == digits[8]) &&
        (j == digits[9])
    )
    std::cout << a << b << c << d << e << f << g << h << i << j << std::endl;

    digits[j]--;    }
    digits[i]--;    }
    digits[h]--;    }
    digits[g]--;    }
    digits[f]--;    }
    digits[e]--;    }
    digits[d]--;    }
    digits[c]--;    }
    digits[b]--;    }
    digits[a]--;    }

    std::cout << "Complete" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Working
progress 0
progress 1
progress 2
progress 3
progress 4
progress 5
progress 6
**6210001000**
progress 7
progress 8
progress 9
Complete
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: It's not .... the last digit should at least be one for the nine in the start....

Comment: To Keep for the generations to come to see the sorts of mistakes that I make, or the call of sweet oblivion....  *Sigh*

Comment: I misread the question.   Thank you JC.   Here is a program to atone for my sins.

Comment: It was a pleasant way. For a moment i felt what a lisp machine feels :3

Comment: Euler 5 is similar in some respects

Answer (score 4):

We can solve this mathematically for the general case, which includes `n = 10`.

Let's call our solution `s`, and `p` the subset of `s`, where `s[i] > 0`, that is, the set of represented numbers (any zero is a number or index that is not represented).

We can say that `n = sum of all frequencies = sum p`

Now let's call `p'` the subset of `p` without `s[0]`, which are frequencies only of numbers greater than zero.

Clearly `sum p' = sum p - s[0] = length p`, which is simply the count of how many numbers in `s` are greater than zero.

Remember that `length p = length p' + 1`. Now if `length p > 4`, we know that `sum p' > 4` and we are left with an `m` length partition (`p'`) that must sum to `m+1`, where `m > 3`. The only way this can be done is with `(m-1)` 1's and one 2, e.g., `[1,1,1,2]` in the case of `m=4` (by definition there are no zeros in `p'`). Such a partition could not make sense as a solution to our problem, and so we see that `p`, or the subset of numbers greater than zero in our solution, must have less than 5 elements.

Now we can solve for specific cases:

Every solution must have `s[0] > 0` since a zero in the zero column would invalidate the solution.

`length p = 1` would only be possible if `s[0]` could be both zero and greater than zero at the same time.

`length p = 2` implies `p' = [2]`, and so there are two zeros and two 2's, `s=[2,0,2,0]`

`length p = 3` implies `p' = [1,2]`. Since we know there is only one more `s[i]`, which is `s[0] > 0`, the 2 in `p'` must either refer to itself, in which case we have `s=[2,1,2,0,0]`; or to two 1's and therefore `s=[1,2,1,0]`

`length p = 4, p' = [2,1,1]`. In this case the 2 could only be referring to the two 1's and we must assume `s[0] > 2`, which also means `sum p >= (3+2+1+1 = 7)`. This  is the final / general case: `s[1]=2, s[2]=1`. The last 1 refers to `s[0]` and so its index equals `s[0]`. Remembering that `sum p - s[0] = length p`, we get, `s[0] = n - 4`, and the solution, for length p = 4, n > 6: `s=[n - 4,2,1...1,0,0,0]`

Comment: I arrived at the same conclusion, but I don't really follow your line of reasoning for the n>6 case

Comment: @harold which part are you having trouble following?

Comment: The end, that sum p - length p deal, why does that have n-4 as solution?

Comment: @harold Simple arithmetic: `sum p` was stated equal to `n` early on; `length p` is defined as `4` for the last case I examined. So `s[0] = n - 4`. `length p must be less than 5` was explained earlier. Are you having trouble understanding `sum p' = sum p - s[0] = length p` ?

Comment: Oh nevermind, I just got lost in all those definitions

Comment: @harold too bad, I thought it was quite beautiful how it fits together in the end.

Answer (score 2):

You can use constraint programming.

There is the obvious constraint, namely the definition: every element must be the number of occurrences of that number. That already gives a simple pruning rule: the sum of the items must be `n` (why? well there are `n` items, and whatever number they are they will be counted somewhere).

But we can go one step further. A number `x` in place `i` means there will be `x` `i`'s (not surprising so far), this means that actually the sum of `array[i] * i` (over all `i`) will also be `n`, which is (mostly) a stronger pruning rule (except for zero).

Most of them (for 7 and higher) end up looking like this:

```
n-4 2 1 .... 1 ...
```

With the second 1 located at the index n-4. This pattern doesn't work for some small n's, namely 6 and below, most of which have *no* valid pattern. 4 and 5 are special cases:

```
4: 1 2 1 0
5: 2 1 2 0 0
```